# Is the expected value of this density function $Z$ finite?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

Is the expected value of this density function $Z$ finite?

$$f_Z(z) =
\begin{cases}
{\dfrac{\ln(z)}{z^2}},  & \text{for $z \ge 1$} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{for $z \lt 1$}
\end{cases}$$

I know expected values can be infinite and when I graph this it looks like it has a horizontal asymptote at $y=0$, so it looks like the expected value can be infinite, but I am not sure? Can someone explain theoretically whether the expected value of this density is finite or infinite?

Comment: Is z an integer or a real number?

Comment: I understand that you want to get a better understanding of your original question (you could ask a new one!) through the interpretation of the graph but your original question, related with a proof, was answered and in that way you shouldn't erase the original question that you had in the last paragraph with an edit. That is simply not fair with the three guys that made an effort in answering you.

Comment: I accepted the other three answers, I didn't want to clutter the site with similar questions asked right after the other, but I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
E(Z)&=\int_{\mathbb R} z f_Z(z) dz\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty z \left[0 \times 1_{z < 1} + \frac{\ln z}{z^2} \times 1_{z \ge 1} dz\right]\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty z [0 \times 1_{z < 1}] dz + \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left[\frac{\ln z}{z^2} \times 1_{z \ge 1} dz\right]\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left[\frac{\ln z}{z^2} \times 1_{z \ge 1} dz\right]\\
&=\int_1^\infty z \frac{\ln z}{z^2} dz\\
&=\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln z}{z} dz\\
&= \frac{(\ln z)^2}{2}\biggr\rvert_1^\infty\\
&= \lim_{a \to \infty} \frac{(\ln z)^2}{2}\biggr\rvert_1^a\\
&= \lim_{a \to \infty} \frac{(\ln a)^2}{2}\\
&= \infty\\
\end{align}
or $\displaystyle \lim_{a \to \infty} \frac{(\ln a)^2}{2}$ dne $\displaystyle \because \frac{(\ln a)^2}{2} \to \infty$ as $a \to \infty$

Answer (score 2):

The expected value does not exist, or if you prefer is infinite. For the expression for $E(Z)$ is
$$E(Z)=\int_1^\infty z\cdot \frac{\ln z}{z^2}\,dz.$$
For $z\ge e$, we have $\ln z\ge 1$.
Thus by Comparison with $\int_e^\infty \frac{1}{z}\,dz$ our integral diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Use integration by parts to see that the expected value is infinite. $\int_1^\infty \frac{ln(z)}{z}\,dz=\int_0^\infty u\,du$, where $u=ln(z)$.